# Android: How to use PDFViewer with Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, pdfviewer

I have a requirement where I need to display `PDF` file within my `Android` app. I have used  `PDFViewer.jar` to do so in some of my `Activities`, which is explained here https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library . Now I am stuck up with displaying PDF file inside a `Fragment`. But `PDFViewer.jar` has been limited to `Activity`. I have seen the source code of `PDFViewer.jar` and am unable to convert it for `Fragment`. Can anyone help me please.

Thanks

Comment: You might consider explaining what "PDFViewer.jar" is.

Comment: @CommonsWare PDFViewer.jar is the library which is used to render and view PDF documents inside the android app. Please go through this link https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library

Answer (score 0):

You should take, `PdfViewerActivity.java` (https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library/blob/master/src/net/sf/andpdf/pdfviewer/PdfViewerActivity.java), rename it to `PdfViewerFragment.java`.
Change `extends Activity` to `extends Fragment` in Android Studio, and correct each red line.

Also, don't forget to import the rest of the project (or you'll have missing classes)

You should especially change each need of `Context` (`this`) by `getActivity()` and `findViewById()` by `getView().findViewById(R.id.foo)`.

Surely, it won't be enough, but it's a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

This is load PDF in fragment use PDFViewer

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_keluarga, container, false); 
     pdfView = (PDFView) v.findViewById(R.id.keluargaPdf); 
     pdfView.fromAsset("tiga.pdf").load();

     // Inflate the layout for this fragment     
     return v;    
}
```